# Unexpected extra backslash when joining a list of string in C# with an escape character in ASP.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, python-requests

I'm develop an ASP.net API with the code except below.
And I want to join a list of string in C# using an escape character(newline) but I dont' know what's part of my code that add an extra '/' in the output.

DBConnect is a class that generate an SQL query string. (try to make a tiny ActiveRecord)
Test_table is a model class.
TesttableController is a controller class.

and then I try to get the result with python using Requests framework.

```
public class DBConnect
    {
        private List<string> _selectList = new List<string>();
        private List<string> _tableList = new List<string>();
        private List<string> _whereList = new List<string>();

        public string getQueryString()
        {
            this._selectList.Add("*");
            this._tableList.Add("test_table");
            this._whereList.Add("name = 'Boat'");

            string selectList = "";
            if (this._selectList.Count > 0)
            {
                selectList = String.Join(", ", this._selectList);
            }
            else
            {
                selectList = "*";
            }
            string tableList = String.Join(", ", this._tableList);

            // somewhere near this part generate the error. ///////////////////////////

            string queryString = "SELECT " + selectList + "\n" + "FROM " + tableList;
            string whereList = "";
            if (this._whereList.Count > 0)
            {

                whereList = String.Join("\n", this._whereList);
                whereList = "WHERE " + whereList;
            }
            queryString += "\n" + whereList;
            queryString += ";";
            return queryString;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
    }

public class Test_Table
    {
        public string get()
        {
            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
            db.from("Test_Table");
            db.where("name","=","Boat");
            return db.getQueryString();
        }
    }

public class TesttableController : ApiController
    {
        public string GetTestTable() {
            Test_Table sb = new Test_Table();
            string result = sb.get();
            return result;
        }

    }
```

python output

```
>>> r.text
34: u'"SELECT *\\r\\nFROM Test_Table\\r\\nWHERE name = \'Boat\';"'
>>> print r.text
"SELECT *\r\nFROM Test_Table\r\nWHERE name = 'Boat';"
36: "SELECT *\r\nFROM Test_Table\r\nWHERE name = 'Boat';"
```

Comment: You tried Environment.NewLine?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at the string in the debugger, and it is THAT which is adding the extra escape. The actual string will not have that extra escape (assuming your code is exactly as you show it here); it's purely a debugger display artifact.

Comment: @Matthew, why would the debugger add a backlash? `"hello\\n"` is not the same string as `"hello\n"` at all.

Comment: The code works exactly as expected for me...

Comment: Its giving the proper output https://dotnetfiddle.net/ll0Yxp each word in a new line
When debigging it will show that extra slash  for escape chracters

Comment: Sorry to everyone, I have just edited my question with my actual code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I was assuming the OP wasn't reporting things accurately. (He wasn't, as it turns out, but in a different area.) It looks like the Python output which is munging the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Environment.NewLine`:

```
List<string> stringArray = new List<string>();

stringArray.Add("hello");
stringArray.Add("Awesome");
stringArray.Add("World");

string s =  string.Join(Environment.NewLine, stringArray);
Console.Write(s);
```

**Output:**

```
hello
Awesome
World
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and output come like only with single `'\'`

```
String.Join("\n", stringArray)
"hello\nAwesome\nWorld"
string
```

Maybe you can try `Environment.NewLine`
output:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, stringArray)
"hello\r\nAwesome\r\nWorld"
string
```